# Writing to a file using echo

Tags: c++, system

```
void EDataset::PrintErr(const NDataString& ErrMsg){       
   system("echo " + $ErrMsg + "  >> err.txt");
   .... code ....
}
```

It prints blank line as the value of ErrMsg. How come?

Comment: why would you want to write to a file via system()? its horribly slow.

Also $ErrMsg is not legal c++.

Comment: Thanks. But if I were to, how do I correct the statement to get the values printed?

Comment: Also, what is NDataString, what library is it from?

Answer (score 1):

As already @gf mentioned in the comment, `$ErrMsg` is not proper. Also, `NDataString` definition is not clear.

Assuming there is a way to get string out of `NDataString` :

```
void PrintErr(const NDataString& ErrMsg)
{      
    std::stringstream tempString;
    tempString <<"echo ";
        //Get the string out of NDataString... 
        //if ErrMsg was std::string then c_str() will give you const char*
    tempString<< ErrMsg.c_str();  
    tempString<<"  >> err.txt";

    system(tempString.c_str());

}
```

Comment: Thanks. ErrMsg.toCString() gives the string.

Comment: No appropriate function found for call of 'oper
    52]. Argument of type 'tentative class stringstream' could not be converted 
                tempString <<"echo ";

Comment: hope you have included #include <sstream>

Comment: I did. Error still popping up. :(

Comment: I usually use ostringstream instead of stringstream. Maybe that will help with your error.

Also, you need to convert the ostringstream instance to a std::string before you get the C string. Something along the lines of:

system(tempString.str().c_str())